# Translating english to chinese using Microsoft translate service

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, microsoft-translator

I'm trying to translate some english text to chinese using microsoft translation service (azure) and requests library for python.

The problem is that I'm getting wrong characters when receiving the translation.

I have checked the response encoding and it is utf-8, so, this should work.

I use this code for the translation:

```
url = 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en-US&to=zh-CN&textType=html"

headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': secretKey,
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-ClientTraceId': str(uuid.uuid4())
}

body = [{
    'text': string
}]

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
print(response.encoding) # This prints utf-8
response = request.json()
print(response[0]['translations'][0]['text'] # prints garbage
return response
```

What could be happening here?

Comment: What is wrong about your characters? (I *do* hope you don't answer with "they appear to be in Chinese and I cannot read that.")

Comment: I think you should use the official API, its easy, and well documented.

Comment: @AttilaKis I'm using the official Rest API.

Comment: @usr2564301 nice joke. When printing the returned chinese text it just prints odd symbols.

Comment: It was not intended to be a joke. One man's "odd symbols" are another one's perfectly legible text. An example may convince me, though.

Comment: @usr2564301 You can check how the text looks here -> https://snag.gy/diVL8x.jpg

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help. I need to see the *Unicode values*, not some non-descript squares because your terminal does not support displaying Chinese.

Comment: @usr2564301 sorry, what a dumb thing I did :/. Here is the hex dump for the string "How are you?" translated to chinese -> "\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd\xe5\x90\x97\xef\xbc\x9f".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "garbage" that you get is Chinese but it is still encoded as UTF-8, so you must treat it as a raw byte string and decode it.

With the sample result `str`,

```
str = b'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd\xe5\x90\x97\xef\xbc\x9f'
print (str.decode('utf8'))
```

yields

```
你好吗？
```

which is pronounced "Ni hao ma?" and is Chinese for "How do you do?"

Comment: Would you mind commenting how did you know the string was chinese?

Comment: @Notbad: the hex encoded string, you mean? I did not know but seeing those hex values, I had a hunch it was *still* UTF8 encoded. Then it was just a question trying.